# error about angular2-jwt, Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Observable (this module not works in Angular 6)

Tags: angular, typescript

I am a beginner to MEAN Stack and I am creating a simple blog site with Angular 6 based on a year-old tutorial. This tutorial utilizes angular2-jwt for hiding and showing HTML Elements based on Authentication.

When I do install and compile the code, however, I get the following error on the command prompt:

```
**ERROR in node_modules/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.d.ts(3,10): error TS2305: 

Module '"C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/MEAN_SITE/client/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"'
has no exported member 'Observable'.

node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot find
module 'rxjs-compat/Observable'.**
```

What does this indicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the `angular2-jwt` is not compatible with `RxJS 6`. 

You should use the same Angular/RxJS version as mentioned in the tutorial by editing the `package.json`.

Comment: yes you are right.. do you have  any another option to solve this error I have almost completed the project and at last moment I am getting this error I want to hide and show the HTML elements based on authentication like a if a user gets logged in to site then login button should not display  .  thanks :-)

Comment: Post the code that hides the element (why you're not using the `ng-if`?)

Comment: thanks to you for assists  me Now my code is running

Comment: @Jazz Welcome to StackOverflow! If Paulie has answered your question, please consider [accepting this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by "*click[ing] on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in*". This will ensure your question is marked closed for the tags you've added, and rewards Paulie in the process!